# How can I add content to a page after opening the link in a new window/tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add some content into a page that is opened in a new tab/window, and nothing seems to be happening. Here is some of my code:

```
var newWindow = window.open('/Window');
newWindow.document.body.innerHTML += '<div>This is a test</div>';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

as you have tagged jquery:

```
var w = window.open();
var html = '<div>This is a test</div>';
$(w.document.body).html(html);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ypAsY/1158/)**

Comment: This works when I leave the window.open() empty, but I'm trying to load an internal page (/Window) and then add to the body.

Comment: @DavidMyersyou mean the whole current page.

Comment: I mean that I want to load an entire page in a new window (mysite.com/otherpage) and then from the page the user clicked the link on, add content to the new window's body tag.

Comment: @DavidMyers:then you need to write the above code on click of anchor(as you said link) of second page `mysite.com/otherpage`